# python re match unicode character

Tags: python, regex, unicode

Having trouble matching unicode chars with a regex in python

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import re

locations = [
    "15°47'S 47°55'W",
    "21º 18' N, 157º 51' W",
    "32°46′58″N 96°48′14″W",
]

rx = re.compile(ur"""
    ^\d+[°º]
    |
    ^\d+[\xb0\xba]
    """, re.X)

for loc in locations:
    if not rx.match(loc):
        print loc
```

Result:

```
15°47'S 47°55'W
21º 18' N, 157º 51' W
32°46′58″N 96°48′14″W
```

Can't seem to match the unicode chars!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `locations` aren't unicode strings.

```
locations = [
    u"15°47'S 47°55'W",
    u"21º 18' N, 157º 51' W",
    u"32°46′58″N 96°48′14″W",
]
```

Comment: That doesn't matter, Python automatically converts.

Comment: @phihag: `print re.match(u"°", "°")` is None in Python 2.7.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. This "automatic conversion" only works when both sides are subsets of ASCII.